# Microsoft Graph Sendmail API error- Error invalid user

Tags: api, graph, azure-ad-graph-api

Sendmail method in Graph giving error "The requested user is invalid"

Comment: Please add more details about your request and response, including the request body.

Comment: Sending mail using graph API from Azure function like below


 await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Getting Error:
  Message=Code: ErrorInvalidUser
Message: The requested user '5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e@eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a' is invalid.

This (**eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a**) is my Tenant Id but what is this (**5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e**).

I am sending to a default user (AlexW@M365x270547.OnMicrosoft.com) which is already there in my tenant.

Please help , am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

The user which you are using to send email doesn't exist in your O365 tenant.

Please check the users' email account in [O365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users).

And make sure to assign an Exchange Online license to the user.

Just choose the user and click on "Edit" next to **Product licenses**.

[image]

And then select a subscription which includes Exchange Online, for example Microsoft 365 E3.

Comment: Sending mail using graph API from Azure function like below

 await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Getting Error:
  Message=Code: ErrorInvalidUser
Message: The requested user '5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e@eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a' is invalid.

This (**eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a**) is my Tenant Id but what is this (**5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e**).

I am sending to a default user (AlexW@M365x270547.OnMicrosoft.com) which is already there in my tenant.

Please help , am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. it works..

**fromUserEmail** is any valid user of your tenant

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                                                    .Create(clientId)
                                                                    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                                                                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

string fromUserEmail =Xyz@M344x276547.OnMicrosoft.com

graphClient.Users[fromUserEmail ].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();